# Can't install fglrx-core - help

Tags: package-management, amd-graphics, fglrx

So after googling around and finding out wine doesn't work with the AMD drivers, I uninstalled it and the `libopen` dependencies for both AMD64 and i386 as they were conflicting with the installation of `fglrx-core`.

Now, however, when I try and install this, I get this error information:

```
(Reading database ... 208182 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fglrx-core_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-core (2:14.501-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/fglrx-core_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/acpi/fglrx-powermode.sh', which is also in package fglrx 2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/tmp/fglrx-core_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to write (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/fglrx-core_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb
```

the `tmp/fglrx-core_14.501-0buntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb` is the package of `fglrx-core` I'm trying to install, but I have also tried it from my home directory and renaming it but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone got a quick fix? I'm new to Ubuntu and not great at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the fglrx, fglrx-core gives you "Minimal video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators", while the fglrx would give you a more "complete" installation.

like:

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install fglrx

or (includes the catalyst center)

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev

Comment: Does this require a specific repo? fglrx has no installation candidates.

Comment: @Synesso if you're on 16.04 or later, [FGLRX was dropped from the Repos and is no longer supported](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04) - you'll need the open source `radeon` or `amdgpu` driver packages for AMD drivers.